# Why do electrons move as if on conveyor belt in a circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, physics, electron

For example sometimes people will ask whether it matters what side of a component you place a resistor on. Surprisingly, it doesn't matter because electrons behave as if they're all connected together on a conveyor belt -- if they encounter resistance in one spot they slow down everywhere else. It's not as though it's very fast on one side and then slower on the other.

Why is this the case? How do the electrons "know" to slow down even well before they actually encounter a resistor that may be on the other side of a component?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80449/discussion-on-question-by-user51819-why-do-electrons-move-as-if-on-conveyor-belt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do the electrons "know" to slow down even well before they actually encounter a resistor that may be on the other side of a component?

They actually don't. Know, that is.

There are tree parts of this answer. First, they might *never* encounter a resistor on the other side of a component. Considering that speed of electron in a copper is somewhere in micron/s range chances are your particular electron will never even reach that resistor before you turn your circuit off.

Second, what you describing as "conveyor belt" is actually a flow of *energy*, not the movement of electrons. And energy transfer is happening close to the speed of light, which is fast but not instantaneous. Consequently, any changes or disruptions in a circuit *do not happen immediately*, it just looks like that because of high speed of wave propagation.

And finally, if you put one and two together, the resistor placed in a circuit  does not "slow down electrons on a conveyor". What it does is make energy transfer harder, so the total energy flow in the circuit is reduced.

The analogy with water in pipes while being useful is technically incorrect, because the speed of water flow depends on pipe diameter according to  Bernoulli's principle. Furthermore, the amount of electrons in a conductor is *enormous*. If you really want to compare electricity to water you should use at least a river.

Now, the river does not have to flow fast to pass wast amounts of energy. Imagine the force of water pushing down on water wheel lowered into the river. The bigger the wheel, the more power is generated. With big enough wheel even slow river can produce huge force.

So, what happens if you somehow manage to block a river upstream? The speed of flow will be pretty much the same, but the level would drop, and so would the pressure on our hypothetical huge water wheel. That is how resistor in a circuit works. Also important to note, that there will be some delay between blocking upstream and reducing the power downstream, just like it happens with electricity, only on different time scale.

Comment: "There are tree parts ...". They'd be various branches of electronics then?

Comment: @Transistor Frankly, I have no idea. At this level electronics and physics so mixed together. I just tried to explain how I see it, which might have no connection to reality whatsoever. The "IMHO" would be very useful here.

Comment: "Considering that speed of electron in a copper is somewhere in micron/s range chances are your particular electron will never even reach that resistor before you turn your circuit off." I thought electrons moved at the speed of light? A micron per second is super super super slow, no? After Googling I see the "marble in a tube" analogy but do electrons really only slog through the circuit that slowly? Are most of the electrons coming from the battery never actually making it through the circuit, mostly just pushing what's already in the wire through to the other end of the terminal?

Comment: @user51819 Read this on [drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity). "pushing what's already in wire" is pretty good analogy.

Comment: OP was correct: adding a resistor, if it lowers the current in the entire circuit, does "slow down the electrons."  Also the energy-based viewpoint is true as well, but doesn't conflict with the charge-based viewpoint.   OP has figured out that drift-velocity is proportional to current, therefore the loop of electrons inside a loop of copper does behave as a flywheel, or "drive belt."  The flowing charge-carriers are controlled by propagating e-field forces, similar to the metal atoms of a flywheel being controlled by propagating mechanical forces.

Comment: @user51819 To answer your question simply: yes, electrons do actually move that slow. Think about Newton's cradle: when the ball on one side hits the rest of the ones at rest, it doesn't take as long as it did for that ball to move from it's highest position to where it stops for the ball on the opposite end to start moving; the ball on the opposite end starts moving near-instantaneously. Electrons in a wire are constantly smashing into elements in the wire, slowing them to a stop, but the electric potential accelerates them until they crash into something else again...

Comment: ...The electromagnetic field, on the other hand, moves at the speed of light in the given material -- which is not necessarily close to the speed of light in a vacuum. Wikipedia has a decent article on the [speed of electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity) that is directly related to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 2):

For an excellent in-depth discussion of this part of circuit-physics, see "Matter and Interactions" textbook materials, Chabay and Sherwood, in particular [this paper about electrons and circuits](https://matterandinteractions.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/circuit.pdf) (pdf)

---

How do the electrons know?  The communicate with each other via e-fields; via changes in voltage.  From an engineering viewpoint, it's all about voltage-dividers, plus tiny capacitors.

Instead of building a circuit with wires, use 1-ohm resistors for your conductors, and connect 1pF capacitors between every part of your circuit.  These capacitors represent the voltage-fields found in the space around the conductors.

Initially all the capacitors have zero volts across them.  Now, when the power supply is suddenly connected, how fast do the capacitor voltages shift?  They all adjust themselves with RC less than nanoseconds.  A 'voltage-wave' propagates across the circuit at essentially the speed of light.  (This actually happens.  All conductors, electrons, and components are communicating with each other, essentially instantly: nanoseconds.)

After the capacitor-charges have stopped changing, all of your 1-ohm conductors will have a (small) voltage along them, therefore a lengthwise e-field exists inside.  This field applies a force to the copper's electrons, and they all move in response, creating a particular current.  (In a single wire, all the electrons move as one, like pulling on a chain, or like pushing a rod.  Wires contain invisible columns of electrons.)  The current in each resistor-wire is proportional to V/R: the voltage along each "wire," divided by the small wire-resistance.

The voltages throughout your network of 1-ohm resistors are self-adjusting, just like any voltage-divider.   These voltages then determine the currents.  The voltages tell the electrons how to flow.

Here's the key question: what happens when we remove one long wire (remove it, or even short out its resistor?)  All the capacitor-voltages will readjust themselves instantly.  A "wave of readjustment" propagates across the entire circuit.  The node-voltages are all different now.  This informs all the electrons inside the 1ohm resistors to change their speed (their current.)

Key point:  as with plumbing pipes, the electric current is proportional to the speed of the particles.  High current is fast electrons.   Zero current is just halted electrons.  And AC is like an oscillating drive-belt, where the charges wiggle as the energy-waves propagate.  In circuits, energy is always EM waves, and the electrons in conductors are the "medium" for the wave-propagation.   The long columns of electrons are not *like* a drive belt.  They actually *are* a drive belt, not an analogy.  They are driven to very slowly move in a circle.  At the same time they deliver energy instantly to all parts of that circle.  That's the function of drive-belts, whether made of visible rubber, or made of the invisible "electron-sea" within a metal loop.